# making xml to send in http post golang

Tags: xml, go, xml-parsing, http-post

following is my expected req xml to be formed

```
<custom key="234234e324e4">
<document name="sample" location="http://example.com">
</document>
</custom>
```

to make this xml i have used following go code

```
 type Documentxml struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"document"`
    Name  string   `xml:"name,attr"`
    Location string   `xml:"location,attr"`
}
type DeleteXml struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name    `xml:"custom"`
    Key   string      `xml:"key,attr"`
    Document Documentxml `xml:"document"`
}
```

and following code to insert values into it

```html
var requestxml DeleteXml
    requestxml.Key = "12321321"
    requestxml.Document.Name = "sample"
    requestxml.Document.Location = "www.//sample.com"
bytexml, err := xml.Marshal(&requestxml)
 client := &http.Client{}
 url := "http://localhost:8080/searchblox/api/rest/docdelete"
 // build a new request, but not doing the POST yet
 req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(bytexml))
 if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
 }
req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=utf-8")
 // now POST it
 resp, err := client.Do(req)
 if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
 }
 fmt.Println(resp)
```

but here request formed is not as i expected to be formed
**request xml formed is: {{ } 12321321{{ } sample www.//sample.com}}**
please suggest what is going wrong here

Comment: One problem is XMLName is empty in Documentxml and DeleteXml. Therfore the empty `{}` values.

Comment: what should be mentioned instead

Answer (score 1):

Your XML definition is correct and you're getting expected format. However in your question. Field `requestxml.Document.Location` has incorrect URL format value, not sure if this could be problem as per your server.

Play Link: https://play.golang.org/p/oCkteDAVgZ

Output:

```
<custom key="12321321">
  <document name="sample" location="http://www.sample.com"></document>
</custom>
```

---

**EDIT:**

May be your server is expecting XML with header. Like below-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<custom key="12321321">
  <document name="sample" location="http://www.sample.com"></document>
</custom>
```

Your update code with header, play link: https://play.golang.org/p/n4VYXxLE6R